# Finder doesn't show thumbnails for Alias in OS 10.14.2

Tags: finder, icon, alias

Since upgrading to 10.14.2, the Finder doesn't make thumbnails for aliases of jpeg image files, instead, it only displays the generic JPEG icon.
Is this a new bug, or is there a hidden setting somewhere that would correct this?

Answer (score 3):

From [this Apple discussion:](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3669221)

> How the Alias-icon will look, depends on what you see in the "Get
> Info" panel of the original file,
>
> see the above example:
>
> If the "GetInfo" icon of the original file shows the custom icon, the
> alias icon also will. If the "GetInfo" icon of the original file only
> shows a generic icon, the alias icon also only will show the generic
> icon.
>
> To recreate the proper custom icon for an image, open the image in
> Preview or any other image browser, select all of the image (or any
> rectangular selection) with cmd-A, and copy the selection to the
> clipboard. Then paste the clipboard contents into the icon well of the
> image's "Get Info" panel. After that also the aliases should show your
> proper custom icons.
>
> [image]

Comment: The OP asked about thumbnails, not custom icons created by pasting one into the properties of the file.